# Why is fluent-plugin-application-insights set to [UNSUPPORTED]?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, fluentd

We are considering transferring and managing logs output by applications running on Microsoft azure VMs to Microsoft azure application insights using fluent.

However, the public fluent application-insights plug-in is "unsupported".

https://github.com/microsoft/fluent-plugin-application-insights

What is the reason for this?

Isn't the method of transferring application insights using fluent recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some info after contacted with the author `Yanming Tang`:

> Because we are not actively supporting that. App Insights team is
>   recently having a cleaning up process to mark inactive projects as
>   unsupported.
>
> And he also suggests that: you can still use it as a starting point,
>   and can make whatever change you like, but they won't work on feature
>   requests.